# Place an image on an another image in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, image

How can i place the play.png image on the another image in bootsrap? Horizontal and vertically center.

My code:

```
echo '<div class="sidebar_youtube_box">';
        echo '<a href="#" id="'.$vid['sidebar_video_v_id'].'" data-url="'.$vid['sidebar_video_link'].'" class="open_youtube_modal" title="'.$vid['sidebar_video_nev'].'">
            <img src="'.$host.'/images/youtube/'.$vid['sidebar_video_thumb'].'" class="img-responsive">
            <img src="'.$host.'/images/assets/play.png" class="img-responsive play_png">

        </a>';
        echo '</div>';
```

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
}

.play {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="play" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e4/Play-rounded-button-outline.svg/500px-Play-rounded-button-outline.svg.png">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/09/Pexels-photo-126407.jpg/320px-Pexels-photo-126407.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer this (off topic) question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Give the images `position: absolute;` and their parent a `position:relative;`. The images will then be positioned relative to the parent. Use `top`, `left` and `transform` to finish the positioning. You can also use `z-index` to bring one on top of the other. See below and hope it helps.

HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar_youtube_box">
    <a href="#" id="'.$vid['sidebar_video_v_id'].'" data-url="'.$vid['sidebar_video_link'].'" class="open_youtube_modal" title="'.$vid['sidebar_video_nev'].'">
    <img src="'.$host.'/images/youtube/'.$vid['sidebar_video_thumb'].'" class="img-responsive img-stack">
    <img src="'.$host.'/images/assets/play.png" class="img-responsive img-stack play_png">  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sidebar_youtube_box{
  position:relative;
}
.img-stack{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  z-index:1;
}
.play_png{
  z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: Whit that, all the listed images will come an each other. I tryed clear, but that doesnt solved it.

Comment: I used .img-responsive because that's what was in your css but obviously you only want to apply this rule to the relevant images. Trying adding a class to only the images you want to apply this to and change .img-responsive in my css to whatever class you choose. I'll edit my answer so you can see.

Comment: Still the same problems, i show you on a link. The images are on each other. [link](http://www.kepfeltoltes.eu/view.php?filename=450K_pkiv_g_s.jpg)

Comment: Sorry now... I'm really confused. The link you sent shows only one image. It is an image of what looks like several images. Which leads me to assume that the problem is the image and not the code. http://www.kepfeltoltes.eu/images/hdd1/2017/11/26/450K_pkiv_g_s.jpg

Comment: You cant see the full images, because they are behind each other.